# Setting the price for an IOS App individually for countries

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Is this really true, that we cant set the price per country individually in Itunes Connect for an IOS App ?
I mean 1 dollar has a different real value in different countries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's true.

You set the price of your application and that price will be calculated automatically depending on the currency of the country in which your app will be distributed.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation. Is this not a stupid apple concept again ? I mean how can someone pay 7$ in india or in africa. For my android app I lowered the price for poor countries, which is fair I think and gets downloads also. This shows me again how much better Google/Android concepts are.

Comment: People in poor countries who can't afford a $7 app don't own iPhones